# How can I use LSA to reduce dimensionality?

Tags: python

I am currently using  bag of words and tdidf technique to pick out the most important features. I also want to implement LSA(Latent Semantic Analysis) after that to reduce dimensionality. How can I do so? Here is my current code:

```
results = []
with open("/Users/zo/X-train.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        results.extend(line.strip().split('\n'))
```

## Converting to Bag of words and then using tfidf

```
blob=list(results)
vector=CountVectorizer()
Y= vector.fit_transform(results)
vectorizer= TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, stop_words='english', analyzer='word', max_features=10000)

X_train_tf=vectorizer.fit_transform(blob)
print(X_train_tf.shape)
idf=vectorizer.idf_

p= dict(zip(vectorizer.get_feature_names(), idf))
r=sorted(p,key=lambda key: p[key], reverse=True)

with open("Vocab.txt","w") as t:
    for x in r:
        print>>t, x

f = open('/Users/zo/Vocab.txt','r')
vocab_temp = f.read().split()
f.close()
col = len(vocab_temp)
print("Training column size:")
print(col)
```

## Create train matrix

```
row = run('cat '+'/Users/zo/X-train.txt'+" | wc -l").split()[0]
print("Training row size:")
print(row)
matrix_tmp = np.zeros((int(row),col), dtype=np.int64)
print("Train Matrix size:")
print(matrix_tmp.size)

label_tmp = np.zeros((int(row)), dtype=np.int64)
f = open('/Users/zo/X-train.txt','r')
count = 0
for line in f:
    line_tmp = line.split()

    for word in line_tmp[0:]:
        if word not in vocab_temp:
            continue
        matrix_tmp[count][vocab_temp.index(word)] = 1
    count = count + 1
f.close()
print("Train matrix is:\n ")
print(matrix_tmp)

mat_tmp=sparse.csr_matrix(matrix_tmp)
```

The shape of matrix_tmp is (202180,10000) and dtype is int64.
I wish to perform LSA on *mat_tmp*

Answer (score 1):

For your case, it's more efficient to use TruncatedSVD:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=5)
svd.fit_transform(mat_tmp)
```

which will reduce your data to 5 dimensions (of course, you are free to increase this number, if you need - default is 2).

Docs:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html

Comment: Hi, I seem to receive this error by adding the above code to my program:
ValueError: X has 10000 features per sample; expecting 5

Comment: that's quite odd: I don't get why it's expecting the number of features to be 5. if you check the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html), there's an example with 100 features and 100 samples.  Are you sure the error is raised by svd.fit_transform(mat_tmp)?

Comment: no it's not by the fit_transform function, it gives me the error when I run my logistic regression model with the reduced matrix.

Comment: alright, that means the LSA part is done. the fit_transform function should return the reduced matrix with dimensions: (num_samples, 5). The error with the logistic regression is probably due to the fact that you are mixing rows with different dimensions (my best guess).